# Javascript based Google Maps API in Android phonegap app works fine in India but not in the US

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I am working on a cordova/phonegap based geolocation app using Google maps. I am using Cordova 2.4 if that matters for this issue. I am getting the location coordinates from the phone and show it as a marker on the map. I also, use the reverse google's geo-location to get the address corresponding to that location. However, the map thing is working fine in India. It displays the marker on the map and also gets the address for that location. However, when I sent the same app to my friend in the US to test, he could not see the map or the marker and also could not get the address corresponding to that GPS coordinates. He did get the alert for the GPS coordinates (which I had added for debugging purposes).

So, it seems there is an issue probably with the Maps API not working in the US. I sent it to multiple people in the US and all of them had same issues. Whereas it worked in India on multiple device like Nexus 4, Nexus S, Galaxy S2 etc.

The app checks if the location services are enabled (using Cordova plugin) and if not, it asks users to do that.

I then created a console API key and used that but still the same result (console API Key was generated for my gmail account which is based in India).

I would like to know if there are any restrictions to view google maps data for US addresses with API key for an account that is India based, or using no key (which works in India).

ANy help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Manish

UPDATE: fixed the issue. There was another totally unrelated issue/bug.

Comment: Could the API endpoints be geographical?  Maybe you need to check to make sure the URLs to call the API in India are not different from counterparts in the US?

Comment: @Dave They are not as far as I could check. The URLs are very generic. The only thing would be the API key that is linked to a google account which is from India. It does not work in the US even when no API key is specified although works fine in India.

Comment: Are you debugging the API calls?  Getting any 40x or 50x errors?

Comment: Hi @user2912552 can u please tell me how this issue got solved, I am also getting this issue but i am not able to find the root cause. Please elaborate about your unrelated issue/bug